# How can I extend ActiveRecord::Associations to a frozen_record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, yaml

I'm using the [Frozen Record](https://github.com/byroot/frozen_record) gem in Rails to upload a YAML file containing some fixed questions for my app. Once they're uploaded I want to use a SaleQualifier model to grab each question, associate it with an answer, and then use it as a state machine to move through a question tree.

I've got the Frozen Record gem working and the YAML file uploads just fine. When I tried associating the Model with a new Model (SaleQualifier) I got `'method_missing': undefined method 'belongs_to' for Question:Class (NoMethodError)`

As a result I added the include ActiveRecord::Associations components in order to let me associate the new record with my SaleQualifier `Question belongs_to :sale_qualifier`- but this then throws:

`'method_missing': undefined method 'dangerous_attribute_method?' for Question:Class (NoMethodError)`

According to my search, this error is thrown when I've already declared the method beforehand. I don't know where this is defined, but from the Frozen_Record gem files I can see they set up a `FrozenRecord` with the following:

```
module FrozenRecord
 class Base
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml
 end
end
```

I'm starting to think using this gem might be overkill, and perhaps I should just load my questions into a normal `ActiveRecord::Base` model, but I like the FrozenRecord idea, as that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

My code:

```
class Question < FrozenRecord::Base
 include ActiveModel::Validations
 include ActiveRecord::Associations
 validates :next_question_id_yes, :question_text, :answer_type, presence: true
 belongs_to :sale_qualifier
 self.base_path = 'config/initializers/'
end
```

SaleQualifier:

```
class SaleQualifier < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :questions
end
```

Can anyone help me unpick the mess I seem to have dug myself into? Maybe I ought to just dig out the YAML upload functions from FrozenRecord and dump them into my Question model without using the gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, Frozen_Record wasn't really adding much to my app it seems. Given the files are loaded from YAML and there's no Controller, I presume there's no way for the Question records to be updated, unless someone has already compromised my DB and inserted their own questions.yml file.

As such I just changed the Question model as follows to load the YAML and insert it into the Database as new Question records:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :next_question_id_yes, :question_text, :answer_type, presence: true
 belongs_to :sale_qualifier

 File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/initializers/questions.yml", 'r') do |file|
   YAML::load(file).each do |record|
      Question.create(record)
   end
 end
end
```